# Resetting a for loop in flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, for-loop, flutter-web

I am attempting to pull all the Panel options out that would fit in the Final length and put them into a list.

```html
for(var PanelOption in PanelWidthOptions.reversed){
              if(PanelOption == FinalLength[i+1]){
                var panelwidth = int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption);
                FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)).toString();
                print(PanelOption);
              }else{
                if((int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)) % 1 == 0 && int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption) >= 8){
                var panelwidth = int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption);
                FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)).toString();
                print(PanelOption);
                // CalculatedWalls.add();
                }
              }
              
        }
```

But there is cases where 2 of the same panel widths might be able to be used. How would I reset the for loop to make sure all indexes are ran again?

FULL METHOD:

```html
 CalculateLowestCost(){
    for(var i = 0; i < Walls.length - 1 ; i++){
      if(SelectedOptions.length > 0){
        for(var l = 0; l < SelectedOptions.length; l++){
            if(ActualWalls[i] == SelectedWalls[l]){
            FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(SelectedWidths[l])).toString();
            }
            for(var PanelOption in PanelWidthOptions.reversed){
              if((int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)) % 1 == 0 && int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption) >= 8){
                var panelwidth = int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption);
                FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)).toString();
                print(PanelOption);
                // CalculatedWalls.add();
              }
            }
        }
      }else{
            for(var PanelOption in PanelWidthOptions.reversed){
              if(PanelOption == FinalLength[i+1]){
                var panelwidth = int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption);
                FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)).toString();
                print(PanelOption);
              }else{
                if((int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)) % 1 == 0 && int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption) >= 8){
                var panelwidth = int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption);
                FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)).toString();
                print(PanelOption);
                // CalculatedWalls.add();
                }
              }
              
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Can you maybe provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with what you expect?

Comment: @Ivo basically just want to reiterate through the entirety of PanelWidthOptions

Comment: What's the data type of `PanelWidthOptions.reversed`

Comment: Where does the `i` variable comes from.

Comment: @SuganPandurengan Question has been updated with the entire method call. PanelWidthOptions is a data type of Strings .reversed is just to iterate through it in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Try initialzing and declaring the loop variables out side the loop.

When we change the value of particular variable then the loop will continue to some more iteration.

```dart
CalculateLowestCost(){
int i = 0;
int l = 0;
int j=0;
    for(i = 0; i < Walls.length - 1 ; i++){
      if(SelectedOptions.length > 0){
        for(l = 0; l < SelectedOptions.length; l++){
            if(ActualWalls[i] == SelectedWalls[l]){
            FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(SelectedWidths[l])).toString();
            }
            for(var PanelOption in PanelWidthOptions.reversed){
              if((int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)) % 1 == 0 && int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption) >= 8){
                var panelwidth = int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption);
                FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)).toString();
                print(PanelOption);
                // CalculatedWalls.add();
              }
            }
        }
      }else{
            for(j=0; j<PanelWidthOptions.reversed.length;j++){
var PanelOption = PanelWidthOptions.reversed.toList()[j];
              if(PanelOption == FinalLength[i+1]){
                var panelwidth = int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption);
                FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)).toString();
                print(PanelOption);
              }else{
                if((int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)) % 1 == 0 && int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption) >= 8){
                var panelwidth = int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption);
                FinalLength[i+1] = (int.parse(FinalLength[i+1]) - int.parse(PanelOption)).toString();
                print(PanelOption);
                // CalculatedWalls.add();
                }
              }
              
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now to reset the loop change the value of j as `j=0;` where you want to restart the loop.

Add `var PanelOption = PanelWidthOptions.reversed.toList()[j];`

Comment: This gets rid of PanelOption as it was a variable that held the current iteration of the for loop. Now the current value of the reversed PanelWidthOption is able to be found. If J is used in the index it will not be the reversed.

Comment: this does not work as the index operator does not work when .reversed is being used

Comment: Can't understand. Share your latest code

Comment: int j
Type: int

The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable<String>'.
Try defining the operator '[]'. This is the Error that is occurring

Comment: This did not fix the issue. Answer code has been placed and the outcome was 96,84,24 when expected outcome should be 96,96,12

Comment: Whats the actual input

Comment: I figured it out. wrapped in a while loop and break out of the for loop